# Azure Pipeline returns "undefined" in filepath

Tags: azure, gitlab, automated-tests, azure-pipelines

I am running my e2e WebdriverIO on Gitlab Pipeline. Now I am trying to integrate my e2e tests after the deployment on Azure. The tests run after deployment as expected, only that I have a strange error with Azure.

I have a test case to upload a file. Here is how I get the file:

```
const filePath = process.env.PWD + '/test/resources/files/logo.jpg'
console.log('file = ' + filePath);
```

When my tests run on Gitlab Pipeline, the file can be located as follow:

```
file = /builds/hw2yvbjx/0/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/e2e/test/resources/files/logo.jpg
```

But when my tests run on Azure Pipeline, the file is `undefined` as follow:

```
file = undefined/test/resources/files/logo.jpg
```

and the full log is as follow:

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\azagent\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\_xxx\e2e\undefined\test\resources\files\logo.jpg'
```

The path is correct, except that extra `undefined` is added between `e2e` and `test`. Does anyone know why this `undefined` is appended in the path? And how to fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`process.env.PWD` will log as undefined on Windows. The `PWD` environment variable is a 'Linux thing'.

That's why you're seeing this in your log statement in Azure (running on Windows, deduced based on the path starting with `C:\...`) but not in your GitLab job, which runs on a Linux host.

To fix it, you can use `process.cwd()`, which is platform agnostic, instead of `process.env.PWD`.

Comment: Thank you very much. `process.cwd()` fixes the problem !